# How to solve the nearest neighbor heuristic

Tags: c++, arrays, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to solve the nearest neighbor heuristic for the tsp on a small example with a 2d-array in C++. This is my code by now. I want to create tours with the start Nodes from 0 to 6, so I can compare them afterwards (which one has the lowest distance). 
However, after debugging I kind of know where my problem is, but I cannot understand why it is not working. My `visited[i+1]` is not saving the smallestIndex on the next Index.

```
void getNearestNeighbor(float distanceMatrix[][6], int startNode, int visited[6]){

    bool unvisited[6]{ 1,1,1,1,1,1 };
    visited[0] = { startNode };
    unvisited[startNode] = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        float smallestDistance = 100.0;
        int smallestIndex =visited[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {

            if (visited[i] != j && unvisited[j] == true)
            {
                if (smallestDistance > distanceMatrix[visited[i]][j])
                {
                    smallestDistance = distanceMatrix[visited[i]][j];
                    smallestIndex = j;
                }
            }
        }

        visited[i+1] = smallestIndex;
        unvisited[smallestIndex] = false;
        //cout << visited[i] << endl;
    }
}   

int main()
{
    int visited[6]; 
    float distanceMatrix[6][6]{
        { 0, 17, 11, 5.39, 10.8, 8.6 },
        { 17, 0, 10.2, 12.5, 19.1, 25.6 },
        { 11, 10.2, 0, 9.85, 18.8, 19 },
        { 5.39, 12.5, 9.85, 0, 8.94, 13.5 },
        { 10.8, 19.1, 18.8, 8.94, 0, 14 },
        { 8.6, 25.6, 19, 13.5, 14, 0 } };


    for (int srtNode = 0; srtNode < 6; srtNode++)
    {
        getNearestNeighbor(distanceMatrix, srtNode, visited);
        cout << visited[srtNode];
        //calcDistance(distanceMatrix, visited);
    }

    system("pause");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Which is the expected output? Also **please** describe exactly what you are trying to do....................

Answer (score 0):

you code have something error for grammar.

```
visited[0] = { startNode };
```

only an element need not {},you should

```
visited[0] = startNode;
```

and this

```
bool unvisited[6]{ 1,1,1,1,1,1 };
```

initial assignment need "=",you should

```
bool unvisited[6] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1 };
```

and visited need initial or assignment.

Comment: I try copy your code.and change that error for grammar.The program can working.Though I don`t know result is true or false.but it can out result.